# Как научиться программировать на питоне?

Tags: python

Вот собственно хочу научиться программировать на питоне - опыта никакого нет вообще! Что посоветутете?

Comment: На чём умеете?

Comment: Вообще ни на чем.

Comment: Смотря с какой целью, мне кажется. Если нет конкретной задачи, то любой метод плохо пойдёт.

Comment: [Научитесь программировать за десять лет (с переводом)](http://norvig.com/21-days.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Марк Лутц - Язык программирования Python.
Отличная книга

Comment: а ссылочку можно?

Answer (score 6):

Самый классный способ научиться программировать на ЛЮБОМ ЯП - придумать себе задачу, и решить ее на выбранном ЯП.

Answer (score 3):

Рекомендую [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).

Comment: Если не смущает английский язык, то http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/

На русском ещё http://diveinto.python.ru

Answer (score 1):

Лично мне нравится начинать обучение чему-то новому с скринкастов на ютюбе. В ютюбе много чего ищется по запросу "уроки python".

Вторым этапом изучения новых технологий у меня является реализация чего-то простого ради опыта, например пишу простенький форум.

А дальше уже все в продакшен :)

P.S. Как бы это кощунственно не звучало, но изучать по книгам я не советую. Книги читать я умею, в начале 2000-ых читал очень много. Но очень уж сейчас стали хороши скринкасты.